# Python Selenium get element by several class names

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following html:

```
<span class="campaign-settings-list__targeting__value js-campaign-settings-value">abc</span>
```

How can I take this element in using WebDriver in Selenium? I have tried:

```
return WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30, 0.1).until(
            lambda d: d.find_elements_by_css_selector('.campaign-settings-list__targeting__value .js-campaign-settings-value')
        )
```

But am getting a timeout exception. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the selector you need:

```
.campaign-settings-list__targeting__value.js-campaign-settings-value.
```

Note how it does not have a space between the two classes. This can be described as "select elements which posses both classes `campaign-settings-list__targeting__value` and `js-campaign-settings-value`."

The selector you specified is this:

```
.campaign-settings-list__targeting__value .js-campaign-settings-value
```

This can be described as "select elements twith the class `js-campaign-settings-value` which are descendants of elements with the class `campaign-settings-list__targeting__value`."